# Conditionally launch WKWebView for iOS <14 or SwiftUI App for iOS 14+?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, ios14

Our user base for iOS 13 and below is small and would like to serve them only a `WKWebView` that points to our website, especially since it already incorporates responsive design.

Can providing 2 entry points based on version be achieved, such as:

```
#If iOS 14+
@main
struct HonkApp: App {
    ...
}
#else
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    ...
}
#endif
```

How can something like this be done? Any help or advise would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe take a look at [@available](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-availability-checking)

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62935053/use-main-in-xcode-12?