# How to Set up a SwiftUI App for iOS 14 but still default to AppDelegate if iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, appdelegate

I'd like to port my existing UIKit App to use the new `App` API for iOS 14. (but still utilize the `AppDelegate` methods via `UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor`, however I would still like to support iOS 13.  Is there a way I can set up so that if iOS 14, use the `App` as `@main` but if iOS 13 use `AppDelegate` as `@UIApplicationMain`? Even the below code won't compile as my minimum build target is iOS 13:

```
@available(iOS 14.0, *)
@main
struct HockeyTrackerApp: App {

    // inject into SwiftUI life-cycle via adaptor !!!
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            HomeView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this topic answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62935053/use-main-in-xcode-12?

Comment: @Asperi the.blaggy's solution seems to work in iOS 14, but he mentions in his answer that you also need to set up a `sceneDelegate` for iOS 13? Confused why this would be necessary given that if iOS 13 Xcode is reverting to the `AppDelegate` so why would a scene delegate be necessary?