# How to setup SwiftUI app file to allow independent app to deploy on WatchOS 6

Tags: swiftui, apple-watch, watchos, watchos-2, swiftui-list

I am attempting to deploy a SwiftUI app to an Apple Watch Series 2 with WatchOS 6.3, from an iPhone running iOS 15. After connecting the device to Xcode and clicking the build button, I get errors that indicate `@SceneBuilder`, `Scene`, `WindowGroup`, and `NavigationView` are only " only available in application extensions for watchOS 7.0 or newer". Is there a way to configure this file (or some other part of the Xcode environment) to enable the app to work with WatchOS 6.3 or lower?

See the screenshot below. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Well the issue is self explaining, if your watchOS is not support version 7.0 or newer, then you need depend on app, if you do not want depend then you need to have version 7.0 or newer.

Comment: Try setting up the AppDelegate lifecycle https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69703928/how-to-generate-ios-13-swiftui-project-in-xcode/69708009#69708009

Answer (score 0):

Please, check out official example: [Developing a User Interface with SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchos-apps/developing_a_user_interface_with_swiftui). Basically you need to create storyboard-based interface and put a `WKHostingController` there (see InterfaceController.swift above). And there you will load SwiftUI view. You may also look at WWDC 2019 video #219: [SwiftUI on watchOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/219/).