# Error : Camera usage description comes up with Terminated signal 9

Tags: swift, xcode

I have this code, however, I am receiving an error Terminated due to signal 9. Could not figure out what the problem is. I have allowed camera usage description in the info plist file.
APP Delegate. I am trying to access the camera, photo library using this app.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

Content view

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showSheet: Bool = false
    @State private var showImagePicker: Bool = false
    @State private var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .camera
    
    @State private var image: UIImage?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            VStack {
                
                Image(uiImage: image ?? UIImage(named: "placeholder")!)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                
                Button("Choose Picture") {
                    self.showSheet = true
                }.padding()
                    .actionSheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                        ActionSheet(title: Text("Select Photo"), message: Text("Choose"), buttons: [
                            .default(Text("Photo Library")) {
                                self.showImagePicker = true
                                self.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                            },
                            .default(Text("Camera")) {
                                self.showImagePicker = true
                                self.sourceType = .camera
                            },
                            .cancel()
                        ])
                }
                
            }
                
                
            .navigationBarTitle("Camera Demo")
            
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker) {
            ImagePicker(image: self.$image, isShown: self.$showImagePicker, sourceType: self.sourceType)
        }
    }
}
```

Image Picker

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class ImagePickerCoordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    @Binding var isShown: Bool
    
    init(image: Binding<UIImage?>, isShown: Binding<Bool>) {
        _image = image
        _isShown = isShown
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
        if let uiImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            image = uiImage
            isShown = false
        }
        
    }
    
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        isShown = false
    }
    
}


struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIImagePickerController
    typealias Coordinator = ImagePickerCoordinator
    
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    @Binding var isShown: Bool
    var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .camera
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> ImagePicker.Coordinator {
        return ImagePickerCoordinator(image: $image, isShown: $isShown)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = sourceType
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
        
    }
    
}
```

Scene Delegate

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let contentView = ContentView()

        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }

    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
        // This occurs shortly after the scene enters the background, or when its session is discarded.
        // Release any resources associated with this scene that can be re-created the next time the scene connects.
        // The scene may re-connect later, as its session was not neccessarily discarded (see `application:didDiscardSceneSessions` instead).
    }

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
        // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
    }

    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene will move from an active state to an inactive state.
        // This may occur due to temporary interruptions (ex. an incoming phone call).
    }

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
        // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the foreground to the background.
        // Use this method to save data, release shared resources, and store enough scene-specific state information
        // to restore the scene back to its current state.
    }


}
```

Tried changing different values in plist but no luck

Comment: Binding Is only for SwiftUI views they don’t belong in a class. Is there a reason you are using such outdated approaches? Did you go through the proper setup to disable multiple windows?

Comment: I am just trying to crack this example. however, I cannot get it work? Do you mean the error is due to the binding? The error says Connection interrupted. and then Message from Debugger: Terminated sue to signal 9. It works in preview, however, doesnn't work in simulator or actual device

Comment: It could be but it is likely becuase you are using iOS 13 code. The scene delegate is not used anymore and requires additional setup to disable multiple windows.

Comment: You should look at the Apple SwiftUI tutorials for updated examples. SwiftUI has made leaps and bounds since this code was relevant.

Comment: what do you suggest. Could you please help me making the changes?

Comment: You can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69703928/how-to-generate-ios-13-swiftui-project-in-xcode/69708009#69708009) I don’t have an iOS 13 project anymore I stopped supporting it a couple of years ago. Unless you have an exceptional reason to learn iOS 13 I would just look for a newer reference.

Comment: Without the scene delegate, the app still runs the same way. I think its something to do with the info plist file. Any recommendations where and what to make the changes? Can you try copying and pasting the file in your xcode and try running it?

Comment: I tried the method you said above, its still giving me the same error Message from debugger; terminated due to signal 9. Can you please help this code work?

Comment: Or do you have any other method where you can make this code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think your issue stems from

```
Image(uiImage: image ?? UIImage(named: "placeholder")!)
```

`image` is `nil` because you haven't picked an image and `UIImage(named: "placeholder")` expects an ImageSet called "placeholder" in Assets.

If you don't have an ImageSet that will cause a crash.

Here is a full working example.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIImagePickerController
    typealias Coordinator = ImagePickerCoordinator
    
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    @Binding var isShown: Bool
    var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .camera
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {
        context.coordinator.parent = self
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> ImagePicker.Coordinator {
        return ImagePickerCoordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = sourceType
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
        
    }
}

extension ImagePicker {
    class ImagePickerCoordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        
        var parent: ImagePicker
        
        init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
            super.init()
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            
            if let uiImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.image = uiImage
                parent.isShown = false
            }
        }
        
        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            parent.isShown = false
        }
    }
}

struct ImagePickerSampleParent: View {
    @State private var showSheet: Bool = false
    @State private var showImagePicker: Bool = false
    @State private var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .camera
    
    @State private var image: UIImage?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            VStack {
                Group {
                    if let image {
                        Image(uiImage: image)
                            .resizable()
                    } else if let subimage = UIImage(systemName: "camera") {
                        Image(uiImage: subimage)
                            .resizable()
                    }
                }
                .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(maxWidth: 300)
                Button("Choose Picture") {
                    self.showSheet = true
                }.padding()
                    .actionSheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                        ActionSheet(title: Text("Select Photo"), message: Text("Choose"), buttons: [
                            .default(Text("Photo Library")) {
                                self.showImagePicker = true
                                self.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                            },
                            .default(Text("Camera")) {
                                self.showImagePicker = true
                                self.sourceType = .camera
                            },
                            .cancel()
                        ])
                    }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Camera Demo")
            
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker) {
            ImagePicker(image: self.$image, isShown: self.$showImagePicker, sourceType: self.sourceType)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ImagePickerSampleParent()
}
```

And make sure you have gone through the iOS 13 setup listed here

[How to generate iOS 13 SwiftUI project in XCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69703928/how-to-generate-ios-13-swiftui-project-in-xcode/69708009#69708009)