Implementing Facebook App Events in Legacy iOS Project Without Scene Delegate
I'm working on a legacy iOS project where the AppDelegate file exists, but there's no SceneDelegate. I need to implement Facebook App Events following the guidelines provided here:
Facebook App Events for iOS.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios
Given the absence of a SceneDelegate in the project, I wonder if it's necessary to implement one, or if I can proceed with implementing Facebook App Events solely within the AppDelegate. If the former is required, how can I integrate the SceneDelegate without causing breaking changes to the existing project?
Here are some specific concerns:
Is it mandatory to implement SceneDelegate alongside AppDelegate for integrating Facebook App Events?
If SceneDelegate is necessary, what are the steps to integrate it into a legacy project without causing disruptions?
Can Facebook App Events be effectively implemented solely within the AppDelegate file?
What are the potential pitfalls or best practices to consider when adding SceneDelegate to an existing project?
I appreciate any guidance or insights on how to best proceed with integrating Facebook App Events into this legacy iOS project without causing significant disruptions.
Thank you!

Idk about facebook events but this is how you would implement scene delegate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69703928/how-to-generate-ios-13-swiftui-project-in-xcode/69708009#69708009

Scenedelegate is not necessary for Facebook events. You can implement everything in Appdelegate.

According to the provided guideline:

Step 6: Connect Your App Delegate and Scene Delegate

and here doesn't mean you need to implement ApplicationDelegate in both, either App Delegate or Scene Delegate would be sufficient.
