Notification from Shield Configuration should lead to specific view in my app
I have almost everything worked out. When the primary button in any Shield configuration of any pre selected app is clicked the user gets a notification. however at the moment when the notification is tapped it only leads to the MainView() but I want it to lead to a specific View the SwiftUIView(). This is my current Code:
import SwiftUI
import FamilyControls
import ManagedSettings
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isAuthorized = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "HasRequestedScreenTimeAuthorization")
    @State private var navigateToSwiftUIView = false
    @State private var selectedApp: ApplicationToken?

    private let selectedAppKey = "SelectedAppToken"

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                if isAuthorized {
                    if navigateToSwiftUIView, let appToPause = selectedApp {
                        SwiftUIView(appToPause: appToPause)
                    } else {
                        MainView()
                    }
                } else {
                    AuthorizationRequestView(isAuthorized: $isAuthorized)
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .navigateToSwiftUIView, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
                    if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: selectedAppKey),
                       let appToken = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ApplicationToken.self, from: data) {
                        selectedApp = appToken
                        navigateToSwiftUIView = true
                    }
                }
            }
            .onOpenURL { url in
                if url.absoluteString == "test://navigateToSwiftUIView" {
                    if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: selectedAppKey),
                       let appToken = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ApplicationToken.self, from: data) {
                        selectedApp = appToken
                        navigateToSwiftUIView = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications

@main
struct YourApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        return true
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        // Trigger URL to navigate to SwiftUIView when notification is tapped
        if response.notification.request.content.userInfo["navigateTo"] as? String == "SwiftUIView" {
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "test://navigateToSwiftUIView")!)
        }
        completionHandler()
    }
    
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        // Post notification for navigation in ContentView
        if url.absoluteString == "test://navigateToSwiftUIView" {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .navigateToSwiftUIView, object: nil)
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}

extension Notification.Name {
    static let navigateToSwiftUIView = Notification.Name("navigateToSwiftUIView")
}

import ManagedSettings
import UserNotifications

class ShieldActionExtension: ShieldActionDelegate {
    private let selectedAppKey = "SelectedAppToken"

    override func handle(action: ShieldAction, for application: ApplicationToken, completionHandler: @escaping (ShieldActionResponse) -> Void) {
        switch action {
        case .primaryButtonPressed:
            saveApplicationToken(application)
            sendShieldNotification()
            completionHandler(.defer)
        case .secondaryButtonPressed:
            completionHandler(.defer)
        @unknown default:
            fatalError("Unknown action")
        }
    }

    private func saveApplicationToken(_ application: ApplicationToken) {
        // Encode the application token and save to UserDefaults
        if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(application) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: selectedAppKey)
        }
    }

    private func sendShieldNotification() {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Shield Alert"
        content.body = "Access attempt detected."
        content.userInfo = ["navigateTo": "SwiftUIView"]
        
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: nil)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to add notification: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Notification scheduled successfully.")
            }
        }
    }
}

I tried to do some stuff in the info.plist of my app but nothing worked.

This is the “old” way of doing this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69703928/how-to-generate-ios-13-swiftui-project-in-xcode/69708009#69708009

The widget code along final project has the “SwiftUI” way of doing this within its logic click on the large widget and go to the specific character https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=yv6so7ie

And for an advanced app you need a deeper understanding https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/restoring_your_app_s_state_with_swiftui
