# How can I make condition works whether my app should use App protocol or AppDelegate with SceneDelegate

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want control my user device if they got `(iOS 14.0, *)`, if that condition is true I want use App protocol, if the user device is lower than 14.0 but it has `(iOS 13.0, *)` then I want use **AppDelegate** with **SceneDelegate**, here what I did, I cannot code from `(iOS 13.0, *)` if I chose **SwiftUI-life-cycle**, because the App protocol need `(iOS 14.0, *)`, then I end up to creating a **UIKit-life-cycle** to be able code for `(iOS 13.0, *)`, so far so good, but I want control the user device in my **UIKit-life-cycle** app if they have `(iOS 14.0, *)`, if that is true I want change the logic of my app to use **App protocol** instead of **AppDelegate** with **SceneDelegate**, is it possible to do such thing?

Here I add this below code as a file to my project in the same time the AppDelegate and SceneDelegate exist:

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 14.0, *)
@main
struct MyTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

error:

```
'main()' is only available in iOS 14.0 or newer
```

How can I make my app smart to know that for `(iOS 13.0, *)` to < `(iOS 14.0, *)` should use **AppDelegate and SceneDelegate** and for `(iOS 14.0, *)` should use App protocol.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62935735/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi: Thanks I am getting `1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64` error, it does not build